# Dendrogram and HistDAWass package

Tags: r, csv

I am using the HistDAWass package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HistDAWass/index.html) to perform clustering using a script partially provided by the package author.

As the Data1.csv files does not include a column with the row name sample (labels) I get a dendrogram that mark the tree labels as I1...I6.
Therefore, I tried to work with a new file (Data2.csv) which its first column include the labels but I get an error.

I will appreciate if someone can explain me how to generate the dendrogram with the new labels.

Script:

```
library(HistDAWass)
data=read.csv('D:/Data1.csv', header = FALSE)
data=t(data)
Hdata=MatH(nrows=6,ncols = 1)

for (i in 1:get.MatH.nrows(Hdata)){
  tmp=data2hist(as.vector(data[,i]))
  Hdata@M[i,1][[1]]=tmp

}

results=WH_hclust(x = Hdata,simplify = TRUE, method="complete")
plot(results) # it plots the dendrogram
```

Data files (in zip):
http://ge.tt/8yVsiQS2/v/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script contains a way for generating a matrix, where, in each cell there is a `distributionH` object. From raw data (for each row of the csv file) a `distributionH` in the `for` cycle, a new `MatH` (a matrix of distributions) is build.
For building the same from Data2.csv file you should run the following script

```
 library(HistDAWass)
#read data
data=read.csv('Data2.csv', header = FALSE)
#initialize an empty MatH matrix using names from the firs colum of data
Hdata=MatH(nrows=nrow(data),rownames=as.list(as.character(data[,1])),ncols = 1)

#Fill the matrix
for (i in 1:get.MatH.nrows(Hdata)){
  tmp=data2hist(as.vector(t(data[i,2:ncol(data)])))
  Hdata@M[i,1][[1]]=tmp

}
#Do hierarchical clustering
results=WH_hclust(x = Hdata,simplify = TRUE, method="complete")
plot(results) # it plots the dendrogram
```